# specify target interface on for ssh tunnel on the other endpoint

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunnel, network-interface

I want to configure/maintain two routers on different networks, but both are directly connected to a raspberry pi. The configuration should then happen remotely through a tunnel via that RPi.

One router is connected on the Pi's `eth0`, the other on `wlan0`.
Unfortunately, both routers claim the same IP address to be configured, so that cannot be used to distinguish the routers.

When I disconnect one of the routers, I can open a tunnel to configure the other using

```
ssh -L 8090:the.router.ip.address:443 pi@the.rasberry.pi.address
```

and then use `https://localhost:8090/` in a local browser.

Is there a way to have both routers connected simultaneously to the RasPi and distinguish which one to tunnel to? For example using an additional option?

As far as I see, the option `-b` sets the interface on the local host.
An option to set the interface on the other end, the Pi, would be ideal, but I have not found it.

Comment: You need to configure the routers to be in different networks,

Comment: @Bib Yes, this is exactly what I want to achieve through the tunnel via the Pi. Physically, the routers are already in different networks.